# Initialising data into custom model from QAbstractTableModel in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner in Qt's Model/View Framework.
I am having trouble using a QAbstractTableModel subclass (MyModel) with a QTableView.
After creating MyModel object I want to set it to have 2 rows & 2 columns.
I have a initialise function which sets all the class variables & then emits the dataChanged() SIGNAL but still the View is not showing anything.

```
class MyModel : QAbstractTableModel
{
     public:
       MyModel();
       Initialise(double **a, int r, int c);

     private:
       int row;
       int column;
       double **array;
}

MyModel::Initialise(double **a, int r, int c)
{
     array = a;
     row = r;
     column = c;
     emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(r - 1, c - 1));
}
```

I have re-implemented all the required functions for read only access.
But still I am getting a blank window.
Created the above code in Notepad for illustration purpose, so please ignore syntax errors.
I could not find any example in Qt SDK for creating custom model from QAbstractTableModel.
So please let me know what is the correct method of initialising data into a model.

**EDIT:**

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();//currently it is returning from here, why???

    switch(role)
    {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        {
        if(index.column()==0)
            return QString::number(array[index.row()][index.column()]);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is only possible if r and c exceed value rowCount and columnCount.

Comment: also initialization need to modify constructor. You can make a function like your Initialize(..) to modify.

Answer (score 4):

`dataChanged` signal forces the view to update existing items. It doesn't tell it that the row or column count has changed. You should use `layoutAboutToBeChanged` and `layoutChanged` signals instead. You can use them without any parameters.

Make sure that you implemented `rowCount` and `columnCount` virtual functions properly.

I don't know why `index.isValid()` is false in your function. Check the index's `model()`, `row()` and `column()` properties to find out why exactly it is not valid. Generally, it's possible for a view to call `data` functions with arbitrary arguments. Since your view thinks that your model is empty, all indexes are most likely invalid. When you see any rows and columns in the view, you would begin to receive valid indexes.

Also if the initialization is performed only once, it's better to do it before you assign the model to the view.

And do not use `double**`. Use automatic memory managing (e.g. `QVector`) instead. It is C++, after all.

Comment: Hi Pavel thanks for that information I will try those 2 SIGNAL's. the definition of rowCount() & columnCount() is same as shown by @Tab in his answer. Also the index has a NULL pointer for model; row & column are 0. The call to data() is hapening many times after running the application & I have not even moved my mouse. All the time it is failing due to the same reason, checked by qDebug(). So why does my view think my model is empty?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize data in Table you have to redefine data function, rowCount and clumnCount along with constructor of Model . 
suppose you have data int mydataarray[r][c] that is initialized in constructor.

```
   TableModel::TableModel(int r,int c, double **initialdata)
{
    R = r;
    C = c;
    mydataarray= initialdata;
}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch(role)
    {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        if(index.column()==0)
        {
        return QString::number(maydataarray[index.row()][index.column()]);
        }
        break;
}
```

To set number of rows and column redefine

```
int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent= QModelIndex()) const
{
    return R;//R is number of initial rows
}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent= QModelIndex()) const
{
    return C;//C is number of initial columns
}
```

in initialize function that actually you can use to modify but you have to insert rows and columns in model if they are exceeding the initial r and c

```
    void TableModel::Initialize(double **a, int r, int c)
    {
    QModelIndex m = createIndex(0,0);

    if(r>this->rowCount(m)||c>this->columnCount(m))
    {
        QMessageBox m1;
        m1.setText("Exciding r/c "+ QString::number(m.row())+QString::number(m.column()));
        m1.exec();
        return;//add logic to insert exceeding rows and columns here before calling dataChange() function
    }

  mydataarray =a;

    QModelIndex n = createIndex(r-1,c-1);
    this->dataChanged(createIndex(0,0),n);
}
```

refer [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/modelview.html#2-1-a-read-only-table) for further

Comment: AFAIK ::data() is called by QTableView to display data for each cell. But when I am calling index.isValid() in first line inside ::data() it is returning false. That is why it is not displaying anything. Hence I thought my method of initialising is missing something. Probably something related to index. The ::data() that you have shown is somewhat similar to mine only that there are some more checks. It is returning in the first line itself because the index is not valid...

Comment: edited the question, please let me know if this clears the confusion.
And yes I did refer that link. But as you can see above I am getting invalid index's. I dont understand the reason for that.

Comment: I cannot understand how recreating array inside MyModel can help me, nevertheless I will try & let you know.
Also if it helps I found out by debugging that the index has a NULL pointer for model & the row & column values are also 0.

Comment: are you initially setting row and column zero?

Comment: Please check the code again I removed that silly mistake of recreating data again.